# Swift - Poor gradient quality in UIView size animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have the following structure in place:

- main view contains subview1; subview1 is laid out using constraints
- subview1 contains subview2; subview2 also has constraints and I need to animate the size of subview2
- in subview2 I call CGContextDrawRadialGradient to draw a circle with a gradient

The code in subview1 is:

```
    let circle = GradientCircle(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: frame.size), withColor: color)
    addSubview(circle)

    circle.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(centerXAnchor).active = true
    circle.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(centerYAnchor).active = true
    let widthConstraint = circle.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(frame.width * 3)
    let heightConstraint = circle.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(frame.width * 3)

    circle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([heightConstraint, widthConstraint])
    layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
        widthConstraint.constant = 2
        heightConstraint.constant = 2
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
```

Here's a gif to show what the problem is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWP7d.gif

Why does this drop in quality occur and how can I fix it? Obviously, I'm new in Swift and I don't fully understand the whole layout and animation thing, so please help if you can, it's slowly driving me insane :)

EDIT:

Here's the GradientCircle class (which is subview2 in the description above), maybe the problem is with how the gradient is drawn:

```
class GradientCircle : UIView {

var color: UIColor

init(frame: CGRect, withColor: UIColor) {

    color = withColor

    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let locations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let colors = [color.CGColor, GraphicsUtils.darkGrayColor().CGColor]
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace, colors, locations)

    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
    let startRadius: CGFloat = 0
    let endRadius: CGFloat = rect.width / 2

    CGContextClearRect(context, rect)
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, startRadius, endPoint, endRadius, CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation)
}
```